# Why do Unix-like operating systems shut down faster than Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

I've tested many different operating systems on the same machine. Windows 7, 8, 8.1, OS X, Ubuntu, Linux Mint,  Android x86, and Remix OS.

All the Unix-like/based operating systems had in common a near zero shutdown time,  maybe like 3 seconds.

All the Windows versions took considerably longer to shut down,  I am talking about 30 seconds to one minute.

Is there a general reason for this?

Comment: Elaborate on the state in which you've triggered the shutdown? Were you logged in the desktop gui (Gnome/KDE), etc .. ?

Comment: @gollum Yes, I had the GUI open and logged in on all the operating systems, but I would typically have exited all my other programs. The Linux distros would have been using Gnome, Unity, XFCE, etc. It didn't make much of a difference, they had a shutdown time of almost zero, as did OS X and Android x86.

Comment: I've just compared a freshly installed Debian Jessie with Gnome and a frshly installed Windows 10. Both systems with all updates on a identically VM. I was logged in in both VMs and triggered the shutdown from the start menus. Debian: 2 seconds Windows 10: 8 seconds

Comment: That is interesting.

Comment: Also my personal experience is that Windows (7, 8.x, not much experience with 10) is quite snappy after a clean install and that there is a direct proportional relation between boot up/shutdown times and the number of days that have passed since the initial setup. I've never experienced this increasing slowdown (at least not at this rate) under a Debian Linux.

Comment: That makes sense. Although my Windows 8 installation is brand new with hardly anything installed and it still takes like a minute or more to shut down.

Comment: In that case this will give you the definitive answer: http://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown

Comment: I'm actually just curious, looking for a general reason, not just for this particular case. I don't care about trying to make Windows shutdown faster, because I don't use Windows very often. I'm just interested in the theoretical reason.

Comment: They don't always (they can have programs hang on shutdown even more easily as windows)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about Windows (tm) behavior; try superuser?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller This answer is not mainly  about why Windows shuts down slowly. This Question is about why Unix and Linux shut down quickly, compared to Windows. Calling that off-topic just because another OS is mentioned sounds like quite a stretch. "Windows" is one of the tags on this SE, so I don't see how comparing Unix and Linux to Windows is off-topic.

Comment: Just my opinion. You may find more Windows expertise at SU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of **general thoughts** I had over this **general question** :

(1) During Windows shutdown, most services will generate atleast one event on terminating. Sometimes each service may have many events. Eg "NTP Service terminating", "Printer Driver got signal to terminate", "Printer Driver is flushing the queue" "Printer Driver Exitting". These **Events are "objects" and are slow to create and destroy**, which adds up to shutdown time.
During shutdown on unix, most processes simply print a line on the console or /var/log/messages and exit. Much faster.

(2) During shutdown, Windows GUI will save a **lot of state information, most of which is stored as objects**.
CLI on unix has almost nothing to save, except for the shell history file. Most state information is in simple text files. Much faster.

(3) Windows may cache many things and these **caches have to be flushed** to FileSystem on shutdown.
Caches may be handled better on unix, with periodic "fsync" executions, on better FileSystems. Much faster.

(4) Windows may give each process (or service) a lot **more time to exit, and hung processes may stay around longer** until forcibly terminated.
Unix may give less time to each process (or service) to exit, and most processes may respond quickly. Much faster.

If there is a **specific situation**, then there may be a **specific correct answer**, otherwise, we will have to go with vague, inaccurate, simplistic generalizations.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.